# POST Method In C# Web API Recieves Null Model When Enum Is Provided

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to pass this model:

```
public class EquipmentRequestModel
{
    public int PackingBenchNo { get; set; }
    public PackingMaterial Equipment { get; set; }
}

public enum PackingMaterial
{
    Bubblewrap,
    Envelopes,
    InvoicePaper,
    Pen
}
```

Into the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RequestEquipment(EquipmentRequestModel equipmentRequest)
```

However, when I send this request via postman:

```
{
    "PackingBenchNo" : 1,
    "Equipment" : "Bubblewrap"
}
```

The data received via the method is `null`. If I use a numeric representation of the enum value, the model passes the data. However, I would like to use the string representation for readability if possible.

Comment: Are you using .Net Core or Framework?  If Core, are you using Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json?

Comment: I am using .NET Core and Newtonsoft

Answer (score 0):

This response is too long for a comment, even if this may not technically be an answer.

I recreated your situation by creating a fresh Asp.Net Core 3.1 API project (in VS 2019) and it worked as expected.  I added your EquipmentRequestModel and enum and then added the RequestEquipment to the default WeatherForecastController that gets created by the default template.

I added Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 (latest) and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson for DI.  I added AddNewtonsoftJson() to the AddControllers call in Startup.cs.

I POSTed your payload using Postman and it was not null.  I tried both with a string and an int and both times the model came through to the RequestEquipment method without issue.

```
{
    "PackingBenchNo" : 1,
    "Equipment" : "Bubblewrap"
}    
or
{
    "PackingBenchNo" : 1,
    "Equipment" : 0
}
```

Do you have any unusual options set for Netwonsoft in the Startup that could be causing your problem?  Are you using Core 3.1 or some older version? (or 5 beta?)

[image]